# Got Error when I set branch for all Git Submodules

Tags: git

I want to update my all git submodule branches to Master.(previously they are in dev branch)

I referred so many links and executed the below commands and i got the below error.

```sh
PS C:\Users\Mohan\source\repos\MainProject> cat .gitmodules                                                             [submodule "SubProject1"]
        path = SubProject1
        url = https://TestGitSubModules@dev.azure.com/TestGitSubModules/SubProject1/_git/SubProject1
        branch = dev
[submodule "SubProject2"]
        path = SubProject2
        url = https://TestGitSubModules@dev.azure.com/TestGitSubModules/SubProject2/_git/SubProject2
        branch = dev
PS C:\Users\Mohan\source\repos\MainProject> git submodule foreach 'git submodule set-branch --default -- ${sm_path}'    Entering 'SubProject1'
**error: pathspec 'SubProject1' did not match any file(s) known to git
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for SubProject1**
```

can any one help me to get rid of this

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git submodule set-branch --default'
```

Notice the recursion and the omission of a url.
You don't have the remote url in foreach, so you can't give it to track.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i run this command and still returns below error.                          
PS C:\Users\Mohan\source\repos\MainProject> git submodule foreach --recursive 'git submodule set-branch --default'                                                                                                        Entering 'SubProject1'

fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for SubProject1

Comment: @mohan is the remote url accesible?

Comment: Yes, its my own project in devops